# How to fill values in a column based on the value of same columns value in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Initial data looks like

```
name <- c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c")
var1 <- c(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1)
(data <- data.frame(name,var1))
#   name var1
#1     a    0
#2     a    1
#3     a    0
#4     a    0
#5     a    1
#6     b    0
#7     b    0
#8     b    1
#9     b    0
#10    b    1
#11    c    1
#12    c    0
#13    c    0
#14    c    0
#15    c    1
```

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Please post your input and output properly as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cummax` per group of "name"

```
data$var2 <- with(data, ave(var1, name, FUN = cummax))
data
#   name var1 var2
#1     a    0    0
#2     a    1    1
#3     a    0    1
#4     a    0    1
#5     a    1    1
#6     b    0    0
#7     b    0    0
#8     b    1    1
#9     b    0    1
#10    b    1    1
#11    c    1    1
#12    c    0    1
#13    c    0    1
#14    c    0    1
#15    c    1    1
```

---

Since you tagged this question with `dplyr` you could also do

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(var2 = cummax(var1))
```